# how to send email use code with McAfee blocks it?

Tags: email, block, send, mcafee

no matter what language i use to send email programingly (like js,perl,php and so on),it always failed because McAfee blocks them.
so i am wondering if we can send email even McAfee is installed on machine?
or we can use another similar way to succeed to send mail to receiver?

Comment: don't know if there is a workaround. but you can add your port to your safelist through Access Protection. (If your allowed). See: http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/cannot-send-email-from-my-local-test-application-blocked-by-mcafee/ for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl.exe sometimes has problems running at all with McAfee installed. You should be able to add Perl.exe to the exceptions in McAfee to correct that problem. If you still can't send mail from Perl after it has been added to the exceptions list, try to verify that McAfee doesn't have port 25 blocked. I believe all outbound mail is sent through port 25, SMTP. You should be able to open this up with McAfee as well, but that might be a security risk.

In my past experience, adding Perl.exe to the exceptions list resolves almost all problems with programmatically reaching out to the internet from Perl applications/scripts.

Comment: if not add perl.exe into the exception list,can we get a method to send email ?